# Cordova - Is it possible to configure Windows App Icons and Splash Screens in config.xml?

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to configure the icons and splash screens in the config.xml file before creating the windows app's platform folder? If so, how?

I've looked through the documentation on the [phonegap site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens), but don't see a way to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In **config.xml**, to change icon properties:

If Windows Phone8,

```
 <platform name="wp8">
          <icon src="res/wp/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
          <!-- tile image -->
          <icon src="res/wp/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />
 </platform>
```

If Windows8,

```
 <platform name="windows8">
          <icon src="res/windows8/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
          <icon src="res/windows8/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
          <icon src="res/windows8/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
 </platform>
```

Windows Phone specifies a single splash screen image:

```
windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg
```

Please refer [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html) documentation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for us. Does this only work for PhoneGap Build? Or is it also compatible locally when using "cordova platforms add windows"?